# How would I go about looping back to the beginning?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to get it to where if the number is negative, it has you start over and input another number. I tried doing a while loop but it just put the `System.out.println` and I had gone into an endless loop.

```
    System.out.println("Please input a positive number: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = scan.nextInt();


    if (num < 0) {
        System.out.println("That number is negative.");
    }

    if (num >= 90 && num <= 110) {
        boolean value = true;
    } else if (num >= 190 && num <= 210) {
        boolean value = true;
    }
```

I've done something like this once before and I remember it being very simple once I figured it out haha. I don't have that file to look at unfortunately. Any help?

*Edited begining

```
   int num = scan.nextInt();
   while (num < 0)
   {
   System.out.println("Please input a positive number: ");
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   }
```

*Edit #2

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = scan.nextInt();
while (num < 0)
{
System.out.println("Please input a positive number: ");
}
```

*FINAL Working code

```
   int num;
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

   while (true)
      {
         System.out.println("Please input a positive number: ");
         num = scan.nextInt();

      if (num < 0)
         { 
            System.out.println("That number is negative.");
         }
      else if ((num >= 90 && num <= 110) || (num >= 190 && num <= 210))
         { 
            System.out.println("true");
            break;
         }
      else
         {
            System.out.println("false");
            break;
         }

      }
```

Comment: Show us the code which resulted in an endless loop. Most likely you messed up your `Scanner` - e.g. by instantiating it multiple times inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will prompt the user again if the number is negative, if it's not, it will jump out the loop.

```
   int num;
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

   while (true)
   {
      System.out.println("Please input a positive number: ");
      num = scan.nextInt();

      if (num < 0)
      {
        System.out.println("That number is negative.");
      }
      else if ((num >= 90 && num <= 110) || (num >= 190 && num <= 210))
      {
        break;
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using this with some minor adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean value;    
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = scan.nextInt();

while(num < 0) {
   System.out.println("Please enter a positive number: ");
   num = scan.nextInt();
}

if (num >= 90 && num <= 110) {
       value = true;
} else if (num >= 190 && num <= 210) {
       value = true;
}

// rest of your code
```

Place it in a `while` loop that runs as long as the number is negative.

Comment: Okay so I edited the begining (see edited original post) and I'm coming up with a `java:14: error: cannot find symbol`

Comment: There is no need to create a new `Scanner`. Keep using the same one.

Comment: Don't make a new `Scanner`. You're also forgetting to reassign `num` to new input (thus giving an endless loopà.

Comment: That's the only scanner in the code. When I remove it I get `java:14: error: cannot find symbol`
   `int num = scan.nextInt();`
Sorry if I'm not understanding very well, I'm only in my first year.

Comment: Also, isn't `int num = scan.nextInt();` assigning new input?

Comment: Look at my edit, I've changed it a little. I have put the declaration of `value` outside the if statements: it would give compile errors if you're creating two variables named `value`.

Comment: I ended up using d.moncada's code with some minor adjustments as seen in the final edit of the original post. Thanks alot for the help though. Will be good to know in the future :D

Comment: That's exactly the same as I have, except his `if` statements are inside the `while` loop. Place them outside of it like I show. If you place them inside it will perform all the `if` statements before asking you to enter a positive number.

Comment: Alrighty. I'm not sure why but his just seemed a little easier to understand.